# How to get the field on focus in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Hello Sir I m making an app in which i got stuck in a problem please help me out ...

in one page i m getting the data from server and displaying that data on the page now i m use Focusable for highlighting them ...now my requirement is that when focus come on any data the it should change the field ie exmple: printing the name on which focus is present ..

following is the code which is showing the data on the page now it is working on field change where i need to click the label field ....

```
package com.Tally.app;

import com.Tally.screenParams.BankList;
import com.Tally.screenParams.CrDrList;
import com.Tally.screenParams.SearchList;

import net.rim.device.api.system.Display;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Color;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.DrawStyle;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.FieldChangeListener;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Manager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.MenuItem;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Menu;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.HorizontalFieldManager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.VerticalFieldManager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.decor.BackgroundFactory;

public class LowerCreditors extends VerticalFieldManager implements
        FieldChangeListener {
    // class Lower extends

    static LabelField[] CrDrLabels;

    public LowerCreditors() throws Exception {

        super(VerticalFieldManager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);

        CrDrLabels = new LabelField[CrDrList.VendorNameArr.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < CrDrLabels.length; i++) {
            final int t = i;

            VerticalFieldManager hfm = new VerticalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH) {

                protected void sublayout(int Width, int Height) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    super.sublayout(Width, Height);

                    setPositionChild(getField(0), 15, 0);

                    setPositionChild(getField(1), Display.getWidth()
                            - getFont().getAdvance(CrDrList.VendorValArr[t])
                            - 10, 0);
                }
            };

            CrDrLabels[i] = new LabelField(CrDrList.VendorNameArr[i],
                    LabelField.FOCUSABLE ) {


                 public int getPreferredWidth()
                   {
                       return 210; // fix width
                   }




                protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {


                    fieldChanged(this, 0);
                    return true;
                };
            };


            LabelField Value = new LabelField(CrDrList.VendorValArr[i]);

            hfm.add(CrDrLabels[i]);
            hfm.add(Value);

            add(hfm);


        }



    }

    protected void paintBackground(Graphics g) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        g.setColor(0xB8E0B8);

        g.fillRect(0, 0, net.rim.device.api.system.Display.getWidth(),
                net.rim.device.api.system.Display.getHeight() + 2000);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        super.paintBackground(g);
    }

    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        graphics.setColor(0xB8E0B8);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, Display.getWidth(), 20);
        graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        super.paint(graphics);
    }

    protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        setExtent(net.rim.device.api.system.Display.getWidth(),
                net.rim.device.api.system.Display.getHeight());
        super.sublayout(net.rim.device.api.system.Display.getWidth(),
                net.rim.device.api.system.Display.getHeight());

    }

    public void fieldChanged1(Field field, int context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    protected boolean abc(int status, int time) {

        navigationClick(1, 1);

        Dialog.alert("Called......");
            return false;

    }


    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = 0; i < CrDrList.VendorNameArr.length; i++) {

            if (field == CrDrLabels[i]) {



                String LN = CrDrLabels[i].getText();
                // SearchList.cname=cn;
                CrDrList.cname1 = LN;

                LabelField cname1 = CrDrLabels[i];
                System.out.println("cnnnnnnnnnnnnnn : "+ cname1);
                CrDrList.selLad = CrDrLabels[i];
                System.out.println("Creddddddddddddddrrrrrrr"+CrDrList.selLad);

                abc(i, i);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

waitng for reply ..

Comment: okk sorry if possible please help me out from this issue ....

Answer (score 2):

Couple things you could do:

1. You can set a `FocusChangeListener` on each Field and do whatever needs done in the `focusChanged()` method.
2. Use `getFieldWithFocus()` or `getLeafWithFocus()`
3. Override each LabelField's `onFocus()` method

Edit for comment

Overriding `onFocus()` on your LabelField. Just add this to the other methods you're overriding:

```
protected void onFocus(int direction) {
    //do things that need done when the label gets focus
}
```

And if it needs to do something when it loses focus

```
protected void onUnfocus() {
    //do things that need done when the label loses focus
}
```

Comment: Did you change your `LabelField Value = new LabelField(CrDrList.VendorValArr[i]);`
call to `LabelField Value = new LabelField(CrDrList.VendorValArr[i]){ //the methods I showed you};`

Answer (score 0):

on navigation movment try this.

```
protected boolean navigationMovement(int dx, int dy, int status, int time){
    System.out.println("field name with focus is...."+getLeafFieldWithFocus());
return super.navigationMovement(dx,dy,status,time);
}
```

Comment: hello sir i tried doing that but the thing is i m getting the data in array not single data ...i wanted to display the data one by one as soon as it got focus on that....here the code and result ....code